# How to get errors from the OpenCL Compiler using LWJGL

Tags: c++, visual-studio, scala, opencl, lwjgl

We're working on a project using OpenCL/LJGWL. We can get back the error code if the OpenCL code fails to compile (e.g. error code -45), but we can't get further information on what failed and why.

In a similar project, using Visual Studios and C++, we got this information. Is it possible to get error details using LWJGL?

Thanks for any suggestions!